# 【AWS SDK PHP】Unable to access SecretsManager from ECS by IAM role

Tags: amazon-iam, aws-secrets-manager, aws-php-sdk

I have a php application running on ECS Fargate 1.14.
aws-sdk-php version is 3.

I want to get secret value stored in AWS SecretsManager by IAM Role, not by AWS Access key/ID for a security reason.
I set SecretsManagerClient like this.

```php
$config = [
   'version' => '2017-10-17',
   'region' => 'ap-northeast-1',
 ];

return new SecretsManagerClient($config);
```

I didn’t add ‘credentials’ because I want to access SecretsManager by IAM role.

The “Task Role” (not Task Execution Role) of my container has policy “SecretsManagerReadWrite”.

However, I can’t access SecretsManager with this error.

```
Error: [Aws\Exception\CredentialsException] Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata service. (cURL error 7: (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)) in /share/swell/cgi-bin/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Credentials/InstanceProfileProvider.php on line 240
```

What does this message means?

I know AWSClient looks for credentials in a order below:

```
1 Load credentials from environment variables.
2 Load credentials from a credentials .ini file.
3 Load credentials from an IAM role.
```

Doesn't this situation apply to No.3?

Or am I attaching the wrong policy?

#### Add info on 2021/06/18

I changed the policy attached to ECS Task Role to "PowerUserAccess". The error message changed to 404.

```
2021-06-18 01:52:12 Error: [Aws\Exception\CredentialsException] Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata service. (Client error: `GET http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:
```

Answer (score 1):

It was because EC2 and ECS have different locations for obtaining credentials information.

- EC2

```
http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/
```

- ECS

```
http://169.254.170.2$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI
```

I had to set environment variable "AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI" to my web app container.
I added this line to my Dockerfile and now I’m able to access SecretsManager.

```
RUN echo 'export $（strings /proc/1/environ | grep AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI）' >> /etc/bashrc
```

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=273767